# Left trim 1 character in Acrobat DC

Tags: acrobat

I am looking to Left Trim the first character of field "`Test Left`" in **Acrobat DC**.

I have a text field ("`Test Left`") that I want to pull each character (text field will always have 7 characters) and insert each of those characters into their own calculated field ("`Calc 1`"). Comb does not work as the form is already built and combing does not fit into premade slots.

Is there any other settings or events that the "`Calc 1`" field needs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JavaScript...

```
this.getField("Test Left").valueAsString = this.getField("Test Left").valueAsString.slice( 1 );
```

No need to remove the space in the field name. But you'll need to add that calculation to some other event... probably "On Blur". If you add it to the field calculation event, it'll just strip the string until it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, I'm not sure for what you are looking for.

To trim the first carachter of a string you can use string.slice(1).
With string.replace(" ","") or string.replace(/\s+/g, '') you can remove whitespaces.

If you want to rename the field you must recreate using the acroJs doc methods getField, removeField and/or addField.